# Spring AMQP - Jackson2JsonMessageConverter setup _TypeId_ with interface instead of concrete Type since version 2.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-amqp

## The problem

We have upgraded our Spring-boot version from 2.0.5 to 2.1.8.
As a result, Spring AMQP upgraded from 2.0.6 to 2.1.8 also.

Since then `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter` is unable to parse answer messages coming from methods annotated with @RabbitListener because they return an interface (actually declared as a generic in the code). And this interface is used to set the message `_TypeId_` property .

with version 2.0 it used to set TypeId with the actual concrete class.

I did some digging and here is my understanding of the problem (code will follow)

When the method annotated with @RabbitListener returns, the `MessagingMessageListenerAdapter#onMessage` is invoked and encapsulates the result in a `InvocationResult` Object, which contains a `genericType` property.

This `genericType` is set up from the return type of the method annotated with @RabbitListener.

Then, it is used by the `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter#createMessage` method to setup `_TypeId_` property.

On the other side, the `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter#fromMessage` can then parse the Json using this propery to find out the actual Type.

The problem is that, since the introduction of `InvocationResult` and `genericType`, our method annotated with @RabbitListener is declared as returning an interface and so the `_TypeId_` property is set up with the interface instead of the actual concrete class. Here is the bit of code from `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter#fromMessage` (actualy from `AbstractJackson2MessageConverter`)which has changed (among other):

```java
if (getClassMapper() == null) {
            getJavaTypeMapper().fromJavaType(this.objectMapper.constructType(
                    genericType == null ? objectToConvert.getClass() : genericType), messageProperties);
        }
        else {
            getClassMapper().fromClass(objectToConvert.getClass(), messageProperties); // NOSONAR never null
        }
```

Since genericType is not null and contains the interfaceType... you can see our trouble.

Prior to version 2.1, we add no problem since the Jackson2JsonMessageConverter#createMessage() was always directly using `objectToConvert.getClass()`:

```java
        if (getClassMapper() == null) {
            getJavaTypeMapper().fromJavaType(this.jsonObjectMapper.constructType(objectToConvert.getClass()),
                    messageProperties);

        }
        else {
            getClassMapper().fromClass(objectToConvert.getClass(),
                    messageProperties);

        }
```

## The code

Here is our code:

```java
public abstract class AWorker<I extends RequestDtoInterface, O extends ResponseDtoInterface> {
   
    @RabbitListener(queues = "${rabbit.worker.queue}"
            , errorHandler = "workerErrorHandler"
            , returnExceptions = "true")
    public O receiveMessage(I inputMessage, @Header(LoggerUtil.LOGGER_MDC_ID) String mdcId, @Header(RabbitConstants.CONTEXT_INFO_HEADER_KEY) String contextInfoStr) {

       if(inputMessage instanceof RequestDtoFirstImplementation.class){
           return new ResponseDtoFirstImplementation();
       }else{
           return new ResponseDtoSecondImplementation();
       }
    }

}
```

Of course, the content of `receiveMessage` method is simplified, the point is that the actual implementation can return differents concretes types depending of the input concrete type

## Possible solution

I figured two possibles workarounds, but none is really nice or easy to maintain.

The first would be to use a `RemoteInvocationAwareMessageConverterAdapter` to encapsulate the `Jackson2jsonMessageConverter`.
If I do that, the `MessageConverter#toMessaget(Object object, MessageProperties messageProperties)` is called instead of `MessageConverter#toMessage(Object object, MessageProperties messageProperties, @Nullable Type genericType)` and so we fall back to the old way.
But that sounds more like a hack than a proper solution. And if `RemoteInvocationAwareMessageConverter` changes its behaviour, we are back to the initial problem.

The second would be to use an existing ClassMapper but, even if it works, that sounds more difficult to maintain (especially when it comes to trustedPackages if we have a lot of class to serialize coming from different packages). Or implement a customClassMapper which also add a bit of work to do.

Since it used to work fine prior to version 2.1 I'm not sure it's absolutely necessary to reimplement ClassMapper.

But I can't find any simple way to make genericType set up with the concrete type

Comment: This appears to be a regression due to [AMQP-807](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-807). Please open a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues).

Comment: thank you @GaryRussell , I do that.